# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') in Recat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm working on React app and I get this error message from console. Also it point this code row

response.js

`var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)`

express.js

`var res = require('./response');`

I was getting some express errors like "crypto, fs, zlib etc." then I created "config-overrides.js" and this errors gone. Then I get this "Response" error after. What should I do to define prototype.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the following URL can help? https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3659#issuecomment-768412388

Comment: I saw it but it's not real answer